# How did the golden arrow prevent an explosion?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of the latest episode of Doctor Who (8x03, Robot of Sherwood), how did the golden arrow help the ship to get out?

Shouldn't it be melted and transformed first?

Comment: The arrow didn't prevent the explosion. It prevented the ship from falling back down.

Comment: but how? because it delayed explosion i think ?

Comment: I think you can chalk it up to bad writing.

Comment: @calccrypto - For the record, I actually think that this episode's level of bad writing is on a par with Voyager : Threshold.

Comment: @Richard I don't remember that episode well enough. What was your opinion of it?

Comment: @calccrypto - I would consider it to be the worst written episode of the entire Trek franchise.

Comment: @Richard Ah. That might explain my memory problem. I agree.

Comment: This ending made no sense. The ship actually has a gigantic bullseye on it.

Comment: Mycroft dropped the ball on this one.

Comment: I think you can chalk it up to TERRIBLE writing. If a single golden arrow was enough to save the ship, why did the Doctor not simply grab one of the many golden plates that the freed slaves had and plop it in the engine right there and then?

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister Maybe those werent made of pure gold? I agree, nonetheless.

Comment: @calccrypto - if so, why are the robots/the sheriff giving away the purest gold in the land as a prize; while simultaneously raiding all villages in search of whatever (less pure) gold they can get their hands on? Doesn't really add up.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister ... terrible writing?

Comment: @calccrypto, yep as I said above :) sorry for the rhetorical questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The script is actually pretty indistinct on the actual technobabble explanation.

The Doctor works out that the robots are creating a...

> "matrix of gold to repair the engine's circuitry"...

but recognises (from the speed at which the engines are powering up) that there is insufficient gold for it to reach orbit, presumably as a result of their premature departure. Note that their plan was *never* going to work since the ship was too damaged but this lack of gold means that the ship will explode before it reaches a safe distance from the ground.

By firing an

> "*arrow of pure gold*"

into the

> "*ruptured engine pod*"

they add some additional gold to the engine circuitry, creating a temporary surge of power. This allows the ship to attain orbit, but doesn't prevent it from exploding.

Comment: oh the pod was ruptured, and here i thought that ship just had horrendously bad insualtion

Comment: It looked like the arrow struck the side of the ship and stayed there, stuck with the tip in the side. This made me even more confused.

Comment: I can't help thinking they were referencing back to the Pompeii episode with stone circuits